# How do I filter dotfiles out recursively using find in bash?

Tags: bash, find, dotfiles

I've searched far and wide but can't seem to find the answer to this seemingly simple question!

I have a directory that contains some dotfiles (they happen to be `.git` but the could easily be `.svn` and maybe even something else) and some non-dotfiles.  I'm searching for a general function that will list all subdirectories of this directory, *except* the ones beginning with a period `.`.

I'm thinking it's some variant of `find . -type d` but I've tried several incantations and come up short.

Something like

```py
def find_files(listing, dir):
    for entry in listdir(dir):
        if isdir(entry) and does_not_begin_with_dot(entry):
            listing.append(entry)
            find_files(listing, entry)
```

(Surprised nobody's asked this - maybe there's a more bash-ish way that I'm not seeing?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -type d | grep -v '/\.'
```

***...or...***

```
find . -type d -a ! -name '.?*' -o -name '.?*' -a ! -prune
```

Comment: Wont `find -type d -a ! -name '.?*' -o ! -prune` do as well?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -name '.*' -prune -o \( -type d -print \)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but to recursively list all subdirectories in bash I usually do something like

```
ls -R | grep /
```

Works a lot faster than some find options I tried. The disadvantage is that using ls I get extra colon at the end, but that is not a case for me.

//edit Ok, I tried other find answers from here and they work quite fast... but they are harder to remember than ls. :)